# Unconfirmed transaction for 10 days. Please help.

Tags: transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions

Unconfirmed transaction from my wallet. Here are the details.
https://blockchain.info/de/tx/2b91804cada49e52774d3c4fd3c02e3932c03b358c8ea4d74abc4d407d5f429c

How can I increase the transaction fee or what do I need to do to get the transaction through?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your listed fee is 44 sat/B.

From [this page](https://bitcoinfees.21.co/), you can probably expect anywhere from 30 minutes to 12 hours at that rate.

Since your transaction was submitted more than 10 days ago, I wonder if there is some other reason it isn't getting confirmed?

Comment: Your transaction is now confirmed.   I think you were just unlucky that it took so long.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's confirmed. Highly appreciated, abelenky!

Comment: Actually, I do have another unconfirmed transaction from my wallet.
https://blockchain.info/de/tx/ee2c05fe58e375f6ec71e4becb6219c673c934569eb2e88fc498f5a42a78ca52
Any help possible?

Comment: Your listed fee is 19 sat/B.  According to the site https://bitcoinfees.21.co/ your transaction may take a very long time at that rate.   If the speed of transactions is important to you, I recommend a higher rate: around 250 sat/B.  (That may still take as long as 6 hours)

Comment: Happy to increase the fee. How do I increase the fee on this transaction? I'm using Bither wallet.